# select id from same row as username and password

Tags: c#, mysql

i am currently trying to program an application using c# where you make "money" by clicking on a button, i cant find how i can select the money int from the database in the same row as username and password and then write to the same row + 1. i dont know what to try since i cant find anything to try. i wanted to try something with my login code below to do select money from ... but i cant since the variable gets converted into an int to make sure they're in the same row.

```
MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from users where username = '" + usrNameBox.Text + "' and password ='" + pswrdBox.Text + "'";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        i = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());

        if (i == 0)
        {
            loginStatus.Text = ("Invalid Username or Password");
        }
        else
        {
            menu fm = new menu();
            fm.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
```

thanks (im making this for my friends and i, not going out to the real world so im not worried about encrypting anything or whatever.)

Comment: So you and you're friends aren't part of the "real world"? In which fictional dimension do you live then? Jokes aside, do it properly from the start, i.e. parameterized queries and hashed passwords. Things might get "real" faster than you know. To fix it then, if you don't miss it completely, causing disastrous effects, is much harder than doing it right now. Plus it's just good thing to get used to for later projects which might be "real" from the beginning.

Comment: please never use concat strings  use** prepared statementsalways** see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html  sencond never save plain passwords. see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57124095/5193536

Comment: @nbk "prepared statements" is an unrelated concept that some databases need and some don't; the problem is the lack of parameters, not prepared statements; more detail: https://blog.marcgravell.com/2017/12/dapper-prepared-statements-and-car-tyres.html?m=1

Comment: What problem are you seeing currently? You're only testing the count (albeit badly - just `i 
= dt.Rows.Count;` should be fine) - it should work. What is happening?

Comment: What's the  issue you are facing with this code?

Comment: they are all mentioned in my comment you have two variables that we don't see. follow the link from Mark and there is explained how sql injection works. 2nd the password don't seems to be hashed. A compromised server and as far as we have seen over the years everybody looses theier data so never saves the passwords in your database, only the hashed ones. Last but not least you see Marks 1st comment, you could use your select query and use it in a prepared statement and gain nothing because the sec. problems are still there, only when you use parameters by using AddWithValue you gain security.